# Data Persistence in Camunda when starting a process Instance through JAVA API

Tags: java, camunda

In this code I am working on, I can start a process instance through JAVA API and also through Camunda cockpit. 
There is really no difference in both the workflow except for data persistence.

When I run HistoricProcessInstance on a process instance that was started by JAVA API, I get no result in query.
But, the same query gives result if I started the process instance with Camunda cockpit.

Starting through JAVA API:

```
public String start process (some parameters...){
    Response jsonResult = target.path(serverPathREST).path(path).path(component).path("start")
                            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                            .post(Entity.entity(jsonBody, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
}
```

Here, I get the response 200 from server and process instance also starts (visible in Camunda cockpit).

The other way I start is through Camunda cockpit directly by entering respective parameters.
In my process diagram, (After a start symbol there is a service task: to keep it simple) this service task has a query which retrieves information on current process instance.

The problem is that when the process has been started through Camunda cockpit, this query retrieves the respective row from database; but if the process was initiated via JAVA API, this query retrieves empty result. I have persisted the state already using asyncafter=true.

Comment: It's not clear what your asking. Also, please provide your code example. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, more details added. Couldn't add an image as I am new here, need minimum reputation of 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. The process instance which started through JAVA API would always trigger a process instance of previous version. I had to write a different process to make sure I was starting a process from latest version every time.

Comment: What does "writing a different process" mean? If you use startByProcessKey, it will always take the latest version by default ...

Comment: There are two POST methods here: (1).  POST /process-definition/{id}/start

(2). POST /process-definition/key/{key}/start (starts the latest version of process definition)